# convert single column to row using scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to convert following table values , ideally all column C4 row values will become columns and respectively indicator will be displayed

```
C1 C2 C3 C4
a  b  c  9
x  y  z  6
A  B  C  3
```

Expected output:

```
C1 c2 c3 9 6 3
a  b  c  1 0 0
x  v  z  0 1 0
A  B  C  0 0 1
```

I want to solve the problem using Scala and spark .
spark version 2.1.1 
Scala 2.11.8 version

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can improve your post (which would make it more likely to get good helpful answers) by adding the code you've tried so far. Without any code - it's hard for people to know what exactly it is you're missing, and often times questions with no code at all get closed or downvoted, see http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use `groupBy/pivot` as follows:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("a", "b", "c", 9),
  ("x", "y", "z", 6),
  ("A", "B", "C", 3)
).toDF("C1", "C2", "C3", "C4")

df.groupBy("C1", "C2", "C3").
  pivot("C4").agg(count(struct("C1", "C2", "C3"))).
  na.fill(0).
  show
// +---+---+---+---+---+---+
// | C1| C2| C3|  3|  6|  9|
// +---+---+---+---+---+---+
// |  x|  y|  z|  0|  1|  0|
// |  a|  b|  c|  0|  0|  1|
// |  A|  B|  C|  1|  0|  0|
// +---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: this is what i am looking for thank you

Comment: If this resolves your problem, could you close out the question by accepting the answer?